# How should I write down the alternating group $A_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I didn't understand how to write down the alternating group A3. 
Is this the group consisting of only the even permutations? Also, what familiar group is this isomorphic to?

Comment: Yes, this is the group of only the even permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$.  For the second question, start by writing down this group; it will have a very small order, so it should be easily recognizable from its Cayley table.

Comment: "Also, what familiar group is this isomorphic to?" It depends which groups you are familiar with. I mean, one could *presume* that you are familiar with some groups, but that same person might also *presume* that you are familiar with other kinds of early results of group theory which, however, you do not seem keen to use.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, $A_3$ is the set of all ***even*** permutations in $S_3 = \{id, (12), (13), (23), (123), (132)\}$.

Remember that an even permutation can be written as the product of an even number of transpositions. The identity of any symmetric group is even, because id *can* be written as the product of two transposition.  In this case, e.g. $id = (1,2)(2, 1)$.

Note also that $(123) = (12)(23)$, and $(132) = (13)(32).$  So,  $$A_3 = \{id, (123), (132)\}.$$

Since $|A_3| = 3$, and the fact that there is only one group, up to isomorphism, of order $3$, $$A_3 \cong \mathbb Z_3,$$  where $\mathbb Z_3$ is the cyclic group under addition modulo $3$.

Comment: You can also write the identity as the product of no transpositions. Seems a more reasonable way to write down the identity in terms of transpositions, and is in fact (obviously) the minimal number of elementary transpositions one needs.

Comment: True...@Pedro.  Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 2):

You can also have an isomorphism with the following matrix group:

$$I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ C^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Explanation: if $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is the canonical basis

- $I$ will sent all $e_i$ on themselves,
- $C$ will send $e_1$ onto $e_2$,  $e_2$ onto $e_3$,  $e_3$ onto $e_1$, that's a cycle !
- $C^2$ will... be as well $C^{-1}$, because $C^3=I.$

Answer (score 0):

Its elements are the  $3$-cycles and the identity

$\begin{cases}
f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=1 \\
g(1)=3, g(2)=1, g(3)=2 \\
Id
\end{cases}$.